# Dual-boot: EFI System Partition is RAW in Windows, readable with LiveCD

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 16.04, filesystem

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot with Windows 10 on my laptop, and at a certain point I ran a gparted 'check' on my /dev/sda1 partition (where Windows Boot Manager and Grub are). Now Windows won't recognize the volume, as it appears as RAW in diskpart.

Ubuntu won't boot, Windows won't boot either. The ASUS BIOS says "drive not present" beside the usual boot options. I have an Ubuntu LiveCD, and when I boot it I can access all of my partitions, and it still sees my /dev/sda1 as a fat32 EFI System Partition though. Boot-repair did nothing, /fixboot and /fixmbr did nothing either. Chkdsk won't work on RAW filesystems, so... I'm kinda lost here.

Is there a way to simply "change" the fs from RAW back to FAT? If not, since I have access to all the files inside /dev/sda1, should I back them up, format the volume and then restore?

I still have access to my files and kinda don't want to screw things up right now.

Many thanks in advance,

swoust

edit:

Thanks to everyone for your input.
I decided to backup my data and erase everything from my drive. I then installed only Ubuntu, because I didn't really want the dual-boot anymore. 
Of course this solved everything, and now I have a clean install.

Comment: +1 For not doing anything in oder to avoid loss of data!

Comment: Back the ESP - efi system partition up. It is not large so easier copied. Sometimes when corrupted we had to suggest full back up, erase, reformat to fat32 with boot flag and restore files. And then it worked. You may be able to use testdisk to see if FAT32 has backup BS or boot sector. NTFS does and can be repaired. Does this work? `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sda1` change from sda1 to your partition if not sda1. Issue is partition boot sector (PBR or BS) or first sector of partition is corrupted.  PBR is similar to MBR in BIOS.

Comment: I tried testdisk, but it literally takes ages to analyse my disk, and doesn't seem to be the solution. The fsck only gave:  `/dev/sda1: 310 files, 17517/76645 clusters`. I backed the 310mb image up, now I guess the only solution is to erase and format?

Comment: By the way, when I mount `/dev/sda1` and list the contents, I get `boot-sav  BOOTSECT.BAK  EFI`. Is there anything that can be done with that, maybe with a Windows Recovery CD?

Comment: Yes, just as oldfred said, make a new fat partition in it's place, restore the data from the backup and set the proper flags in gparted or gnome-disks and hope that the data itself is fine. Otherwise reinstall Windows Boot Manager from Installation Media with bcdboot and reinstall grub from live media.

Comment: After you fix the problem with the ESP, be sure to disable both [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernation](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in Windows. Those features probably caused the problem, since they're recipes for disaster in a dual-boot environment.